# Does anyone know how to overlay a equalized CDF plot with equalized histogram in matlab?

Tags: histogram

I am willing to overlay a equalized cdf with equalized histogram in matlab.
But it's really hard to find any recommends.
so if you can, would you please let me know about that?

Comment: Maybe you want to overlay the PDF with the histogram?

Comment: No I want to overlay plot with cdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'hold on' with a histogram:

```
[n,x]=hist(rand(1,100),20);  % find the histogram
bar(x,n./sum(n))             % plot normalized histogram
hold on                      % don't delete current plot
plot([0 1],[0.1 0.1])        % plot a uniform pdf
axis([0 1 0 0.12])           % make room around the plot
```

Another example using a normal distribution, which shows how to normalize the histogram so that its area is one:

```
r=randn(1,1000);      % normal random variable
[n,x]=hist(r,25);
delta=x(2)-x(1);
n=n./(delta*sum(n));  % n is normalized so that its area is 1
bar(x,n)
hold on
d=-4:0.1:4;
plot(d,(1/sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-(d.*d)./2),'r')  % plot of the normal pdf
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not realized with equalized cdf. Where can I find equalized CDF in your code?

Comment: Even it was just made by hard plot and not equalized CDF.

Comment: Your question is how to overlay a plot with a histogram, not how to obtain an "equalized CDF" (which I assumed is just a PDF), which is an entirely different question. In my answer, I'm simulating a uniform random variable (with `rand` in the first line), and I plot a uniform PDF in line 4.

Comment: Thanks. this looks like so. I need make to another post same subject.

Comment: @user1917217: I've added another example that shows more clearly how to normalize the histogram to obtain a probability density function (pdf).

Comment: I'm really appreciate your help.

Comment: Especially I want like this. Figure 10 in here  http://cache.freescale.com/files/dsp/doc/app_note/AN4318.pdf

Comment: @user1917217, I see that what you're actually trying to do is improve the contrast in an image using histogram expansion. That's not my area of expertise, so I can't provide further help. However, the document you linked to has step-by-step instructions. I'd suggest that you ask about the specific problem you're trying to solve, and this time, provide all the context you can.

Comment: Got it,thanks, but, anyway.you are helped me.